# Put second string on a position from user input on a first string

Tags: c, string-concatenation, c-strings

I'm starting to learn C and I would appreciate any help with my homework.
I need to make a function that takes 2 strings and a position from user input.
The second string has to go on the position of the first string. For example:

- String 1: `Chocolate`
- String 2: `Cake`
- Position: `3`
- Outcome: `ChoCakecolate`

I need to make this to work with VisualStudio, that's why the "_s".
Debugger says that I have "not enough information" on the "strcat" and "strcpy" lines.

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void concStrings(char  string1[], char string2[], int pos);

int main(void) {
    char lastName[20] = { '\0' };
    char firstName[20] = { '\0' };
    int pos = 0;
    scanf_s("%s", &firstName, 20);
    scanf_s("%s", &lastName, 20);
    scanf_s("%d", &pos);
    concStrings(firstName, lastName, pos);
    printf("%s\n", firstName);
    return 0;
}
// Here is my funcion
void concStrings(char  string1[], char string2[], int pos){
    char tmp[40];
    strcpy_s(tmp, string1, pos);
    strcat_s(tmp, string2);
    strcat_s(tmp, &string1[pos]);
    strcpy_s(string1, tmp);
}
```

Comment: Why using strcat and strcapy, do it using loop it will bcm much easier for u

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Tip: Use `char* x` instead of `char x[]`.

Comment: Check your arguments to [`strcpy_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy). I think you have the order wrong. Compile with `-Wall` or the Visual Studio equivalent (all warnings = on) to see if there's any warnings.

Comment: Might want to check the other functions available in `<string.h>`.  `strncat` seems particularly apropos

Comment: @Tibrogargan: suggesting `strncat()` to anyone is cruelty — it has a ridiculous interface.  Hint: `strncat(dst, src, sizeof(dst))` is wrong, even when `dst` is initialized as an empty string.

Comment: So far, only one of the answers (indirectly) points out that one call to `strcpy_s()` and both calls to `strcat_s()` are wrong — they're missing the length information required by the `*_s()` functions for safety checking. The other call to `strcpy_s()` has the length information in the wrong place. The compiler should be warning you about the mismatches between the prototypes and the calls to the function (if not refusing to compile because of the mismatches), and the debugger is completely correct in telling you that the code is wrong too. (You may also have overflow problems when it's run.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `size_t` instead of `int`. Beyond that, here's a possible implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SZ 50

void concStrings(char *str1, char *str2, size_t pos) // size_t instead of int
{ 
    size_t sz1 = strlen(str1);
    size_t sz2 = strlen(str2);
    if ((sz1 + sz2 + 1) > BUFF_SZ)
    {
        perror("String too long");
        return;
    }
    char temp[BUFF_SZ];
    strncpy_s(temp, BUFF_SZ, str1, pos);
    strcat_s(temp, BUFF_SZ, str2);
    strcat_s(temp, BUFF_SZ, str1 + pos);
    strcpy_s(str1, BUFF_SZ, temp);
}

int main()
{
    char str1[BUFF_SZ] = "Chocolate";
    char str2[BUFF_SZ] = "Cake";
    concStrings(str1, str2, 3);
    printf("%s", str1);
}
```

Output:

```
ChoCakecolate
```

Highlights:

- I've corrected the calls to `strncpy_s()`, `strcat_s()` and `strcpy_s()` by adding the correct length parameters.
- In the example, I used `strncpy_s()` instead of `strcpy_s()` because it clearly suits our purpose here better: copying a known number of characters without incurring a parameter validation error
- You can find references to the standard C11 functions used here (the `_s` functions are optional in C11 and are not implemented on many platforms):

  - [strcpy, strcpy_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)
  - [strncpy, strncpy_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)
  - [strcat, strcat_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat)
  - [strncat, strncat_s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncat)
- You can find references to the Microsoft version of the `_s` functions too:

  - [strcpy_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcpy-s-wcscpy-s-mbscpy-s)
  - [strncpy_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strncpy-s-strncpy-s-l-wcsncpy-s-wcsncpy-s-l-mbsncpy-s-mbsncpy-s-l)
  - [strcat_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcat-s-wcscat-s-mbscat-s)
  - [strncat_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strncat-s-strncat-s-l-wcsncat-s-wcsncat-s-l-mbsncat-s-mbsncat-s-l)

Answer (score 1):

If your `lastName` and `firstName` are both `20` characters long, e.g.

```
char lastName[20] = { '\0' };
char firstName[20] = { '\0' };
```

then both `lastName` and `firstName` cannot fit in `lastName`. If you are putting both in `lastName` then `lastName` must be at minimum `2X + 1` as long as `firstName`.

Additionally, rather than using a temporary string (`tmp`) to concatenate `string1` and `string2`, just make space for `string2` in `string1` at `pos` using `memmove` and then put `string2` in that space with `memcpy`, e.g.:

```
#define MAXC 128

void concstrings (char *s1, const char *s2, size_t pos)
{
    size_t  l1 = strlen (s1),   /* get lengths */
            l2 = strlen (s2);

    if (l1 + l2 + 1 > MAXC) {   /* validate s1 + s2 fits in s1 */
        fputs ("concstrings() s1 + s2 exceeds MAXC\n", stderr);
        return;
    }

    memmove (s1 + pos + l2, s1 + pos, l1 - pos + 1);    /* make room for s2 in s1 */
    memcpy (s1 + pos, s2, l2);                          /* stick s2 in it */
}
```

(**note:** by moving `l1 - pos + 1` bytes you ensure you move the *nul-terminating* character)

A complete example could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 128

void concstrings (char *s1, const char *s2, size_t pos)
{
    size_t  l1 = strlen (s1),   /* get lengths */
            l2 = strlen (s2);

    if (l1 + l2 + 1 > MAXC) {   /* validate s1 + s2 fits in s1 */
        fputs ("concstrings() s1 + s2 exceeds MAXC\n", stderr);
        return;
    }

    memmove (s1 + pos + l2, s1 + pos, l1 - pos + 1);    /* make room for s2 in s1 */
    memcpy (s1 + pos, s2, l2);                          /* stick s2 in it */
}

int main (void) {

    char s1[MAXC] = "Chocolate";
    char *s2 = "Cake";

    concstrings (s1, s2, 3);
    printf ("%s\n", s1);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/concstrings
ChoCakecolate
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the second argument in these calls

```
scanf_s("%s", &firstName, 20);
scanf_s("%s", &lastName, 20);
```

is specified incorrectly. It should be specified as

```
scanf_s("%s", firstName, 20);
scanf_s("%s", lastName, 20);
```

because the type of the second function parameter is `char *` and the arrays' names used as arguments are already implicitly comverted to pointers to their first elements.

Pay attention to that the header `<stdlib.h>` is redundant in your program. Neither declaration from the header is used.

There is no need to define an auxiliary array and moreover to use a magic number like 40 to perform the task.

The function itself should have the return type char * as most C string functions. The function also should not check whether there is enough space in the first character array to accomodate the string stored in the second character array. It is the client of the function that should guarantee this.

Also if the specified position is greater than the length of the first string then the function should do something in this case. A logical approach is just to append the second string to the first string.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function could be defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * concStrings( char *s1, const char *s2, size_t pos )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );

    if ( !( pos < n1 ) )
    {
        strcat( s1, s2 );
    }
    else
    {
        size_t n2 = strlen( s2 );
        memmove( s1 + pos + n2, s1 + pos, n1 - pos + 1 );
        memcpy( s1 + pos, s2, n2 );
    }

    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    char s1[N] = "Chocolate";
    char s2[] = "Cake";
    size_t pos = 3;

    if ( strlen( s1 ) + strlen( s2 ) < N )
    {
        puts( concStrings( s1, s2, pos ) );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Unable to include one string in another: not enough space>" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
ChoCakecolate
```